# Phalcon's ORM inheritance?

Tags: php, inheritance, orm, phalcon

How can I implement models inheritance with phalcon's ORM ? I mean in doctrine I can tell the inheritance strategy and it maps my models to the database. Is that possible with phalcon's ORM ? Thanks !

Comment: You mean automatically create table schema from a model definition?

Comment: No, like I have a class Person and 2 other classes that extend this one. Doctrine for example has a strategy to map this to tables. I don't see that in phalcon's ORM. So It basically expects to always have a database schema to work with and that's not always the case, sometimes you want to create the database schema out of your models.

Comment: Doctrine make these child Person classes to work with the original person table or or create new ones? You can use `setSource` to define which table a Model should use. AFAIK, Phalcon only works passively with the database schema, so anything that you want to use should be predefined in your schema.

Comment: Doctrine has 2 strategies: 1. Using a field called discr to determine the class, 2. Creating tables as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the answer is no, there's nothing like this yet. In [Phalcon's Model Documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html) and anywhere else I've always seen the ORM working passively with the database schema (never creating or changing any schema at all).

Not sure if it helps but you can extend a Model and make it use the same table of their parent:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model as PhModel;

class Person extends PhModel {...} //This will use a pre-existent 'person' table

class Employee extends Person 
{
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'person'; //This will also use the 'person' table
    }
}
```

If I misunderstood your question, please provide more details.

Comment: I guess you can do that but it's not very elegant. Thank you very much !